# Spring + Angular Http Cache Not Clearing

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, http

From what I've researched, both Spring and Angular do not enable http caching by default. ie, you have to explicitly add in the option if you need that functionality. However, for some reason my http requests just pile up as I navigate from page to page, whereas on a normal web page they would disappear after leaving a page (unless you cached them). I've searched quite a bit but I cannot find a similar situation/problem. One idea I had is that it might be a browser setting within Chrome but I haven't found anything on that.

Here is an example. The first picture is on a secondary page, and the second picture is after navigating back to the home page. You can see that the requests do not leave the queue after doing so. Third picture is an example of a response I'm getting. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Secondary Page]

[image: Back to Home page]

[image: Headers]

I'm also wondering if there is something on my classpath that could be causing this, because both Spring and Angular have caching disabled by default.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is something specific within Spring/Angular that could cause this by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your server to disable caching of files. For development, you can just select the *Disable Cache* option and keep the development console open to disable caching.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. The thing I don't get is that Spring by default does not enable caching, so I'm not sure why it is behaving this way. I started looking into @EnableAutoConfiguration because that includes the class "CacheAutoConfiguration", but it shouldn't turn on cache by default.

Comment: Not sure about the spring but browsers do caches some stuff by default unless you explicitly disable or change them :)